# How to delete old csv file from multiple folder in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm working on a project where i need to delete old .csv file from multiple branch folders using for-each loop container in ssis?  Can any one guide me through . I'm new to ssis world by the way so an examples and screenshot will help me indeed.

Kind Regards,
Bis

Comment: it seems that you have two working answers, with helpful information, why ignoring them until now?

Comment: @Yahfoufi Coz it didn't helped me.

Comment: @Biswa have you tried my suggestions? i didn't get any feedback until now! Why it didn't helped you?

Comment: @Hadi Hi Hadi, sorry i kept it on hold for the moment as we are working on a different project. I will try it and let you know brother.

Answer (score 1):

use a script task and write like this:

This will delete all files from folder and subfolder

**C# Code**

```
using System.IO;

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\","*.csv",System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
  File.Delete(filePath);
```

**Make a SSIS Package with a Script Task**
[image]

**Enter the code as shown**

> Remember to change the path to your specific folder

[image]

Comment: Just updated the SearchOption to use System.IO then it should work for you. Works perfectly here. You shouldnt use any foreachloop

Comment: Thanks brother. But as i mentioned i'm new to ssis , i just couldnt make it work. Any screenshot will help me alot.

Comment: Just add a script task and paste the above into the main script. Add the namespaces system.io under namespaces. I Will make screenshot tomorrow

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to achieve this:

## Using File System Task

Just add a Foreach Loop, and select the Directory that contains the csv, inside the foreach loop container add a `File System Task` that delete these files. You can read these detailed article for more informations: [Delete files from specified folder using File System Task in SQL Server - SSIS](http://www.sqlideas.com/2011/12/delete-files-from-specified-folder.html)

## Using a Script Task

Just add a Script Task, and Select the Script Language as Visual Basic, and write the following code:

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim strFiles as String() = Io.Directory.GetFiles("C:\MyDirectory\","*.csv",IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    For each strFile as String in strFiles
        IO.File.Delete(strFile)
    Next

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```